# Bash Scripting - Variable Concatenation

Tags: bash, shell

Completely new to Linux and Bash scripting and I've been experimenting with the following script :

```
declare -a names=("Liam" "Noah" "Oliver" "William" "Elijah")
declare -a surnames=("Smith" "Johnson" "Williams" "Brown" "Jones")
declare -a countries=()
readarray countries < $2
i=5
id=1
while [ $i -gt 0 ]
do
  i=$(($i - 1))
  rname=${names[$RANDOM % ${#names[@]}]}
  rsurname=${surnames[$RANDOM % ${#surnames[@]}]}
  rcountry=${countries[$RANDOM % ${#countries[@]}]}
  rage=$(($RANDOM % 5))
  record="$id $rname $rsurname $rcountry"
  #record="$id $rname $rsurname $rcountry $rage"
  echo $record
  id=$(($id + 1))
done
```

The script above produces the following result :

```
1 Liam Williams Andorra
2 Oliver Jones Andorra
3 Noah Brown Algeria
4 Liam Williams Albania
5 Oliver Williams Albania
```

but the problem becomes apparent when the line `record="$id $rname $rsurname $rcountry"` gets **commented** and the line `record="$id $rname $rsurname $rcountry $rage"` **is active** where the exact output on the second execution is :

```
 4William Johnson Albania
 2Elijah Smith Albania
 2Oliver Brown Argentina
 0William Williams Argentina
 3Oliver Brown Angola
```

The file I am reading the countries from looks like this :

```
Albania
Algeria
Andorra
Angola
Argentina
```

Could you provide an explanation to why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your countries input file has DOS-style `<cr><lf>` (carriage-return line-feed) line endings.

When you read lines from the file, each element of the `countries` array ends up looking like `somename<cr>`, and when printed the `<cr>` moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line, so the contents of `$rage` end up overwriting the beginning of the line.

The fix is to convert your countries input to use Unix style (`<lf>` only) line endings. You can do this with `dos2unix <inputfile> > <outputfile>`, for example.